# Как присвоить wchar[256] переменную?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Есть текстовый файл в котором хранится ссылка к примеру (https://ru.stackoverflow.com) какая там ссылка неизвестна. Я считываю ссылку из файла и записываю её в переменную line.

```
string line;
ifstream writeT("test.txt");
writeT.is_open();
getline(writeT, line);
```

Далее мне нужно как то присвоить значение переменной line в WCHAR, я знаю как присвоить текст L"sometext". Как можно присвоить WCHAR webAddress[256] значение переменной line не зная ссылку?

```
WCHAR webAddress[256] = ;
HRESULT hr = URLDownloadToFile(NULL, webAddress, szFileName, 0, NULL);
```

Comment: Используй ifwstream, как-то так называется.

Comment: У вас в коде нет `wchar` переменных. У вас в есть `wchar[256]` переменная.

Comment: @AnT хорошо, как мне присвоить wchar webAddress[256] значение из переменной line?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если там действительно ссылка, то там набор символов ASCII, и можно просто написать

```
std::wstring wline(line.begin(), line.end());
```

Comment: `wstring wline(line.begin(), line.end());
 WCHAR webAddress[256] = wline;` я правильно сделал, есть да то ошибку выдаёт : для агрегатного объекта требуется инициализация с использованием {...}

Comment: @TheHavlok вы можете вызвать функцию URLDownloadToFile так: `URLDownloadToFile(NULL, wline.c_str(), szFileName, 0, NULL);`
Необязательно использовать массив WCHAR.

Comment: @zenden2k спасибо)

Comment: @Abyx в ссылке могут быть не только ascii-символы

Answer (score 1):

Предложенный до меня ответ подходит только для ASCII строк. Я рассмотрю общий случай, когда входная строка содержит не только ASCII-символы, но и, к примеру, кириллицу.

Предположим, у вас входной файл в кодировке UTF-8.
Вам нужно конвертировать строку в кодировку UTF-16, понятную функциям WinAPI. 
Это можно сделать с помощью WinAPI функции [MultiByteToWideChar](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/stringapiset/nf-stringapiset-multibytetowidechar):

```
std::string line;
// ... пропущено
WCHAR webAddress[256];
if (MultiByteToWideChar(CP_UTF8, 0, line.c_str(), line.size() + 1, webAddress, 256)) {
    HRESULT hr = URLDownloadToFileW(NULL, webAddress, szFileName, 0, NULL);
}
```